# Pass two parameter list in postman api tool

Tags: c#, json, post, postman

please tell me how to pass two parameter list to a method while post in postman api checker tool.

For Example-

```
public IHttpActionResult methodName ( List< int > para1, List< int > para2 )
```

In PostMan tool i have tried like below code in option raw `{{"para1":[1,2,3]},{"para2":[2,3,4]}}` and selected dropdown `JSON(application/json)`.

but i am getting error like

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Can't bind multiple parameters ('para1' and 'para2') to the request's content.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Tell me anyother way to pass the two parameter list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your JSON string in a validator and it showed an error.
I changed it to this format and it passes:

```
[{ "name":[1,2,3]}, { "name":[1,2,3]}]
```

Check if this helps.

**UPDATE**
The proper JSON is this:

```
{"para1":[1,2,3],"para2":[1,2,3]}
```

In the Postman, you need to select Raw->Json.
Also make sure the request is POST, not GET.

It works perfectly on my side.

Comment: Not working Bro, still showing the same error. can you please tell me what option did you select in dropdown(for example: Text or JSON or Javascript)